# npm error Cannot find module './render-template.js'

Tags: npm

Every time I use any npm commad I kepp getting this error .

I tried to delete node.js and reinstall it . but that did not work
even tried to delete the path and do it again and that didnt work too
how can I fix this please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.